# uploading iOS app with watch 2.0 give ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-watch

[image]

I'm working on iOS app with watch using xcode 7.0 by after upload version to iTunes  give `ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary`. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Not very clean but I  believe either : you are on a beta software of Mac OS X or XCode or you should use the latest XCode 7.1.1 I believe but as far as I know this is not mandatory. Are you sure your XCode 7.0 was not a beta one ?

Comment: i'm use xcode 7.0 and xcode 7.1.1

Comment: i know to submit app is to select target and chose archive i tried by using app  and also  try with using  watch app as a target ,  but still invalid -- if i remove watch form app it accepted by store and no problem

Answer (score 0):

Create Xarchieve file by using Xcode, click product->archive

Used this to create archive file and than uploaded using xcode instead of application loader.

[image]

Comment: thanks all  , the problem was that watch icon contain alpha channel

Comment: @MahmoudNasr How did you find this out? Would be good if you posted this as an answer and marked that answer as correct.

Comment: itunes team  send email to customer (account owner )